# Are there any chrome extension VPNs that use the chrome.vpnProvider API?

Tags: vpn, chrome, chromebook

Seems most extensions use the old proxy api which requires giving them full "read and change site data" access. A more recent API is available made for VPNs:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/vpnProvider

But I can't find any that use it.

Anyone know of any?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "what product/service does X?" is off-topic has the list of potential answers could be endless.

Answer (score 1):

This API is for Chromebooks and not the Chrome browser in general: "Important: This API works only on Chrome OS."